# How to Fetch All Rows Of Gridview When Paging is Enabled??

Tags: asp.net

How to Fetch All The rows of gridview when paging is enabled?.

it is allowing to fetch only current fetch rows not entire gridview rows.

Comment: Can't you get the `Datasource` where you can get all the rows?

Comment: Does that mean you want to know how to disable paging? ;)

Comment: What is the purpose behind this..?

Comment: actually gridview is coming on pageload then i m selecting some checkboxex on gridview...

and then i am going to second page of gridview and i m trying to select other check boxes but when i m saving all data it is saving only current page data not all gridview page

Comment: i m getting all rows which has checked box has checked by using.

grdSupplierSearch.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
                                            .Where(a => ((CheckBox)a.FindControl("ckbSelectCompany")).Checked && selectedCompanyNames.Contains(((Label)a.FindControl("lblCompanyNameGrid")).Text))
                                            .ToList();

but it is allowing to save only current page data which are checked not another pages of gridview.

Comment: @KunalShah did you resolve this? Could you share your code? The issue is managing "states" of pages when checkboxes in each row for example are ticked or unticked. Simply turning off AllowPaging is not enough to control more realistic situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We disable paging temporarily and will re-bind the grid so that now we have access to all records in the datasource not just current page records.

Once gridview is binded with all records, you can iterate through gridview rows.

Once we are done with our task, we re-enable paging and rebind the grid.

Here the way to tackle with your condition:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView2.DataBind(); 

    // You can select some checkboxex on gridview over here..

    GridView2.AllowPaging = true;
    GridView2.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Suthar It is Done.

Comment: Yep, doesnt work without calling databind(). Thanks, this helped me aswell.

Comment: This method works, but is risky to use. If someone makes any changes to the code and doesnt realize where the paging is turned off, you could crash some people's web browsers. The setting page index is safer imo.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the Commands Below which I'm using it in my projects. Its logic is so simple, you go through all pages and in every page you go through all rows. You can also get your current page before doing this and after looping all you can get back there ;)

```
//Get Current Page Index so You can get back here after commands
                int a = GridView1.PageIndex;
    //Loop through All Pages
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.PageCount; i++)
                {
    //Set Page Index
                    GridView1.SetPageIndex(i);
    //After Setting Page Index Loop through its Rows
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        //Do Your Commands Here
                    }
                }
    //Getting Back to the First State
                GridView1.SetPageIndex(a);
```

Comment: This is the simpler approach. Turning OFF or ON the AllowPaging is fraught with issues, especially if you don't want to upset the page the client is seeing (would not look nice seeing a GridView expand and shrink all of a sudden), and what if you have checkboxes across all the pages and some are ticked and not ticked? There's a lot more to it and it gets messy with ViewState to control it all.

Comment: This is, by far, the better answer. I'd go as far to say the only answer. Not trying to slight the accepted answerer, because it technically answers the question, but this is way less 'hacky' and a way more professional way of doing things.  Anyone reading this thread should absolutely use this method over the accepted answer.  Don't even question it.

Comment: This is great. Better than messing with paging

Answer (score 6):

Use Following Code And make GridView paging disable

GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();

on **Page Load or Some Other event** where You Want To show All Your Gridview Rows

Answer (score 4):

Before the function of getting the Data from grid just write

```
yourGridName.AllowPaging=false;
```

and after getting the Data write

```
yourGridName.AllowPaging=true;
```

If your function is GetDataFromGrid() then you should go like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
yourGridName.AllowPaging=false;
GetDataFromGrid() 
yourGridName.AllowPaging=true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cant display all rows when paging is enabled.But u can make `Allowpaging=false;` in codebehind in pageload or in some event..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Gridviewname.AllowPaging=false;
}
```

or

```
Protected Void some event(object sender,Eventargs e)
{
Gridviewname.AllowPaging=false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to put a hidden field on the top of the page(outside of gridview) and on click of checkboxes, you should put the related id or some value in comma separated format in hidden field. On submit of the form, you can split the hidden field value string with comma as delimiter and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get value of `e.CommandArgument`. It will solve your issue surely!

```
  protected void GridViewID_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
         if (e.CommandName == "GetDetail")
         {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % GridViewID.PageSize; // !Important
            
            GridViewRow row = GridViewID.Rows[index];
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by "Inside Man" with Page Index is logically correct.
But you don't have to use
GridView1.SetPageIndex(i);
because it just sets the starting row of the current page.
You should directly modify GridView1.PageIndex = i;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35126101)